# C# - Unable to parse XML file generated with Microsoft xsd.exe

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, deserialization

I have created a C# class with xsd.exe from a XSD file. The root element is called ODX. I would like to be able to populate a ODX object by parsing a XML file in a way similar to this:

```
namespace OdxLib
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ODX odxDocument;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("C:\\MCA2014.40_NEW.odx", FileMode.Open))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ODX));
                odxDocument = (ODX) serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                Console.WriteLine(odxDocument.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This looks correct to me.
Anyway I get the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException
Unable to generate a tempoprary class

error CS0030: Unable to convert type 'it.intecs.odx.DISABLEDAUDIENCEREFS' to 'it.intecs.odx.ENABLEDAUDIENCEREFS'.
error CS0029: Unable to implicitly convert type 'it.intecs.odx.ENABLEDAUDIENCEREFS' to 'it.intecs.odx.DISABLEDAUDIENCEREFS'.
```

I don't understand the reason for this error.

This is a sample of the ODX file (the full file is more than 150000 lines):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ODX MODEL-VERSION="2.0.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="odx.xsd">
<!--created by CANdelaStudio::ODXExport201.dll 7.1.101 on 2012-06-12T11:33:41+02:00-->
  <?CANdelaTemplateManufacturer 12?>
  <?CANdelaTemplateName New ECU 2.9?>
  <?CANdelaTemplateVersion 3.0.0?>
  <?CANdelaProtocolStandard UDS?>
  <?ASAMOdxExport201.dll 7.1.101?>
  <DIAG-LAYER-CONTAINER ID="_XXX2014_990">
    <SHORT-NAME>XXX</SHORT-NAME>
    <LONG-NAME>XXX</LONG-NAME>
    <ADMIN-DATA>
      <LANGUAGE>eng</LANGUAGE>
      <DOC-REVISIONS>
        <DOC-REVISION>
        ...
        <COMPARAM-REFS>
          <COMPARAM-REF ID-REF="XYZ" DOCREF="UDS_CPS" DOCTYPE="COMPARAM-SPEC">
            <VALUE>500000</VALUE>
            <DESC>
              <p>
                250000 and 500000 baud shall be supported XXX
                <br/>
              </p>
            </DESC>
            <PROTOCOL-SNREF SHORT-NAME="Diagnostic_UDS_on_CAN"/>
          </COMPARAM-REF>
```

This is a piece of the class generated by xsd.exe on the xsd file:

```
namespace it.intecs.odx {
    using System.Xml.Serialization;


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class ODX {

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("COMPARAM-SPEC", typeof(COMPARAMSPEC), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("COMPARAM-SUBSET", typeof(COMPARAMSUBSET), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DIAG-LAYER-CONTAINER", typeof(DIAGLAYERCONTAINER), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ECU-CONFIG", typeof(ECUCONFIG), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FLASH", typeof(FLASH), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FUNCTION-DICTIONARY", typeof(FUNCTIONDICTIONARY), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MULTIPLE-ECU-JOB-SPEC", typeof(MULTIPLEECUJOBSPEC), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("VEHICLE-INFO-SPEC", typeof(VEHICLEINFOSPEC), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public ODXCATEGORY Item;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("MODEL-VERSION")]
        public string MODELVERSION;

        public ODX() {
            this.MODELVERSION = "2.2.0";
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName="COMPARAM-SPEC")]
    public partial class COMPARAMSPEC : ODXCATEGORY {

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute("PROT-STACKS", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
        public PROTSTACK[] PROTSTACKS;
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName="PROT-STACK")]
    public partial class PROTSTACK {
```

Comment: Can you please post a sample of the XML you are trying to parse?

Comment: The full file is very large...

Comment: That's why I wrote "Sample" :)

Comment: No, I can run the code but when line 'var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ODX));' is executed the Exception is thrown.

Comment: Is it possible that the XSD or XML file is not correct?

Comment: Well, you don't even get to parse the XML - based on what you described that it fails trying to create the serializer, so I wouldn't worry about XML at this point. Did you validate the XSD by itself? Is it one file XSD or does it uses include/import etc.? There's always a possibility the the generated code is faulty, xsd.exe has so many bugs... Is the XSD available as a public download (for independent evaluation)?

Comment: To be more precise the essror is the following: InvalidOperationException
    Unable to generate a tempoprary class

    error CS0030: Unable to convert type 'it.intecs.odx.DISABLEDAUDIENCEREFS' to 'it.intecs.odx.ENABLEDAUDIENCEREFS'.
    error CS0029: Unable to implicitly convert type 'it.intecs.odx.ENABLEDAUDIENCEREFS' to 'it.intecs.odx.DISABLEDAUDIENCEREFS'.

Comment: Can you paste a sample of the XML that has the "ENABLEDAUDIENCEREFS" or "DISABLEDAUDIENCEREFS" elements?

Comment: <xsd:complexType name="DISABLED-AUDIENCE-REFS">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="DISABLED-AUDIENCE-REF" type="ODXLINK" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <!-- Automatically generated wrapper element type -->
 </xsd:complexType>

Comment: Did you generate the XSD file yourself from XML, or was it provided to you? Also, perhaps that element goes by a slightly different name, like "ENABLED-AUDIENCE-REFS". Also, can you post the C# where you see "ENABLEDAUDIENCEREFS" or "DISABLEDAUDIENCEREFS"?

Comment: Both the XSD and the XML are generated by means of a software and are provided to me. I did not generate them. Anyway it looks like the XML is not well formed since minOccurs=1 in the XSD but there is no such element in the XML.

Comment: To find your problem, construct the smallest possible example that illustrates the issue.  If you succeed in getting it down to a sample that fits on a screen or so (say, 25 lines for the schema and 25 lines for the XMLK), there is a good chance that some reader on Stack Overflow can help.  Of course, along the way you may yourself see what the problem is and not need help here; that's a risk you'll have to take.

Comment: You're giving mixed signals here; you said that you're getting the exception at this line `var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ODX));` IF this is the case, you're not even looking at XML yet so the issue has nothing to do with the XML file. If you're encountering at this line `odxDocument = (ODX) serializer.Deserialize(stream);` then you better validate the XML first against the XSD used to create the CS code - most likely that's your problem in this case, invalid XML.